# SQL display low med high as 1 2 3

Tags: sql

I'm very new to this so sorry if I struggle with clarity.

The database I am working from has a column of values stored as "very low, low, medium, high, very high". To try and do maths and visualization of these it would be much better if I had a corresponding column of numbers.

For example I have

| Field | Disease | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Root Rot | Low |
| 2 | Leaf Death | low |
| 3 | Root Rot | Med |
| 4 | Root Rot | Very High |

and I'd like a new column with very low as zero, low as one and so on.

Comment: Better off having a "DiseaseRating" table with Rating (int) and RatingName (varchar) columns. Your current Table should replace your existing column with a FK to your new table. Then use a JOIN on subsequent queries

Comment: I agree, however I have no control over the tables or the data stored therein, I'm read-only essentially.

Comment: Then how do you plan to add " a new column with very low as zero, low as one and so on."

Comment: Ah, yep I get you. I cannot save to the database, just wanted the data to be displayed differently. The answer below got me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you could use the CASE command, for example:

```
SELECT id
     , disease
     , CASE WHEN rating = 'low' THEN 0 
            WHEN rating = 'mid' THEN 1 
            ELSE 'etc' 
       END AS rating
FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a temporary table to join on instead:

**Schema (SQLite v3.30)**

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  `Field` INTEGER,
  `Disease` VARCHAR(10),
  `Rating` VARCHAR(9)
);

INSERT INTO data
  (`Field`, `Disease`, `Rating`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Root Rot', 'Low'),
  ('2', 'Leaf Death', 'Low'),
  ('3', 'Root Rot', 'Med'),
  ('4', 'Root Rot', 'Very High');
```

---

**Query**

```
WITH keys(Rating, Value) AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM (
    VALUES 
    ('Low', 1),
    ('Med', 2),
    ('Very High', 3)
  )
)
SELECT *
FROM data
JOIN keys 
USING(Rating);
```

| Field | Disease | Rating | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Root Rot | Low | 1 |
| 2 | Leaf Death | Low | 1 |
| 3 | Root Rot | Med | 2 |
| 4 | Root Rot | Very High | 3 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vfSDXoUub7cWo3LjvTszqp/1)

Formatting will vary depending on the Flavor of SQL, which you didn't provide.